# Show previous content after a mouseout event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseout

I'm creating a documentation web app template. On the right hand side of my page I have a list of articles in the selected category. With a click event(using jQuery) the previous article is hidden and the new one is displayed.

With a `mouseover` event, a short description of the content is displayed while the original content is hidden.

I'm trying to create a function which displays the original content (prior to my `mouseover` "description content") with a `mouseout` event. The original content is never static.

I thought of creating a `<div>` above the main content articles with the description content and then have the content `<div>` put at `opacity:%100`. The problem with that is my footer gets placed way down the page, which I don't want.

Conceptually I can't figure out how I would do this with Javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<Head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--Recent Library-->

<!--JQuery UI CDN Info-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="indexscript.js"></script>

<title>Documentation Viewer</title>

</head>

<div id="container">
    <body>

        <header>

            <div id="logo">

                <h3 id="logo-title">
                Documentation Viewer
                </h3>

            </div>

            <div id="menu-top-right">
                <ul class="menu-list-main">

                    <li class="menu-li-top" id="option1"><h4>
                    Option 1
                    </h4></li>

                    <li class="menu-li-top" id="option2"><h4>
                    Option 2
                    </h4></li>

                    <li class="menu-li-top" id="option3"><h4>
                    Option 3
                    </h4></li>

                    <li class="menu-li-top" id="option4"><h4>
                    About
                    </h4></li>

                </ul>
            </div>

        </header>

        <div id="body-content">

            <div id="left-content">

                <div id="article1" >
                    <h2>
                    Article 1
                    </h2>

                    <p id="summaryArt1">
                    <!--Enter Your Summary Here-->
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
                    </p>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>

                </div>

                <div id="article2">

                <h2>
                    Article 2
                    </h2>

                    <p id="summaryArt2">
                    <!--Enter Your Summary Here-->
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
                    </p>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>

                </div>

                <div id="article3">

                    <h2>
                    Article 3
                    </h2>

                    <p id="summaryArt3">
                    <!--Enter Your Summary Here-->
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
                    </p>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>

                </div>

                <div id="article4">

                    <h2>
                    Article 4
                    </h2>
                    <p id="summaryArt4">
                    <!--Enter Your Summary Here-->
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
                    </p>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="right-menu">

                <ul id="menu-right">

                    <li class="li-menu-right" id="menuArt1" ><h4>
                    Article 1
                    </h4></a>
                    <p id="art1Hi"></p>
                    </li>

                    <li class="li-menu-right" id="menuArt2"><h4>
                    Article 2
                    </h4></li>

                    <li class="li-menu-right" id="menuArt3"><h4>
                    Article 3
                    </h4></a></li>

                    <li class="li-menu-right" id="menuArt4"><h4>
                    Article 4
                    </h4></a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">

            <div id="logo-image">
                <!--<img src="logo.jpg"></img>-->
                <h4>Documentation Viewer</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="copyright">
                <p id="copyright-text">copyright &copy; <script type="text/javascript">
                var d = new Date()
                document.write(d.getFullYear())
                </script> Documentation Viewer</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</div>
```

```
$("document").ready(function() {
//What to do with the content on the initial load
hideAllArticles();
hideAllSummaries();
$("#article1").show();  
function hideAllArticles(){
$("#article1").hide();
$("#article2").hide();
$("#article3").hide();
$("#article4").hide();
}
function hideAllSummaries(){
$("#summaryArt1").hide();
$("#summaryArt2").hide();
$("#summaryArt3").hide();
$("#summaryArt4").hide();   
}
//Begin Click Functions For Right Menu Article Options
$( "#menuArt1" ).click(function() {
hideAllArticles();
$( "#article1" ).show( 'fold',1000 );
});
$( "#menuArt2" ).click(function() {
hideAllArticles();
$( "#article2" ).show( 'fold',1000 );
});

$( "#menuArt3" ).click(function() {
hideAllArticles();
$( "#article3" ).show( 'fold',1000 );
});

$( "#menuArt4" ).click(function() {
hideAllArticles();
$( "#article4" ).show( 'fold',1000 );
});
//Begin mouseover functions for right menu articles
$( "#menuArt1" ).mouseover(function() {  
$( "#summaryArt1" ).show( 'fold',1000 );
});
$( "#menuArt2" ).mouseover(function() {  
$( "#summaryArt2" ).show( 'fold',1000 );
});
$( "#menuArt3" ).mouseover(function() {  
$( "#summaryArt3" ).show( 'fold',1000 );
});
$( "#menuArt4" ).mouseover(function() {  
$( "#summaryArt4" ).show( 'fold',1000 );
});
//mouseout events for right menu
$( "#menuArt1" ).mouseout(function() {  
$( "#summaryArt1" ).hide();
});
$( "#menuArt2" ).mouseout(function() {  
$( "#summaryArt2" ).hide();
});
$( "#menuArt3" ).mouseout(function() {
$( "#summaryArt3" ).hide();
});
$( "#menuArt4" ).mouseout(function() {  
$( "#summaryArt4" ).hide();
});
});
```

Comment: Without code, it would be very hard to get any help. Please provide your code showing what you have tried.

Comment: What I want to ask is the place you are clicking initially to close the first set of content is it in the div of the content itself or some other place? Is the content generated in static divs or do you create dom elements on the fly?

Comment: Just sent code. Thanks!

Comment: @JeandeToit Content is located in a static div. So is the summary. just realized my summary should not be sharing a div with the content. Clicking is in another place to close div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Had to make a global variable called activeContent.

Set variable to equal the corresponding content div when clicked on menu item.

after mouseout event executes, I set my activeContent variable to .show()

ei.

```
var activeContent = "#article1";


$( "#menuArt1" ).click(function() {
activeContent = "#article1";
hideAllArticles();
$( "#article1" ).show();
});

$( "#menuArt1" ).mouseover(function() {
$(activeContent).hide();
$( "#summaryArt1" ).show();
});

$( "#menuArt1" ).mouseout(function() {  
$( "#summaryArt1" ).hide();
$(activeContent).show('fold');
});
```

Comment: Nice and sure because `.show()` and `.hide()` sets `display` to `block` and `none` respectively, do you have only one article in each page?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity I am going to have several pages that are topic based. The content within those pages are going to be articles on the given topic. Their will be several articles within one page. Thanks for explaining how it works. I'm very new to jQuery. Is a lot of jQuery reference to CSS?

Comment: [jQuery uses CSS selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to target and select DOM elements, so as in your example when you use `$('#article1')` it is expecting to find *one* DOM element with attribute `id="article1"`, so you can't target several articles based on that selector, instead you target them with `$('.articles')`.. just like what I did in the demo https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/erknavar/ of my example which solves the problem of injecting new contents on `mouseenter` and brings back the original content on `mouseout`

Comment: Beside using CSS selectors to target DOM element just like CSS, jQuery has [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate)  function which "Perform a custom animation of a set of CSS properties", as well as these functions `.show()` , `.hide()` , `.fadeIn()` , `fadeOut()` which are shortcuts of `.animation` function.

Comment: Also there's [`.css()'](http://api.jquery.com/css/) which lets you change CSS properties

Answer (score 2):

> I thought of creating a above the main content articles with the description content and then have the content put at %100 opacity. *The problem with that is my footer gets placed way down the page, which I don't want*.

Giving an element an `opacity:0` doesn't hide it, it just fades it out but it stays occupying its space, instead you can use `display:none`

Using `opacity:0` >> [**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/LtjbL4mo/1/) <sup>(*)</sup>

Using `display:none` >> [**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/LtjbL4mo/3/) <sup>(*)</sup>

---

**EDIT:**

> On the right hand side of my page I have a list of articles in the selected category

Because you have more than one article in the page it would be redundant and "buggy" to target them all like `#article1`, `#article2` and so on,  much better to give them a unique class name, i.e: `.articles`, and as the page is ready this code will take the inner html of all `.articles` and push each article content into an array `origContArr` used as a store for the original content.

On `mouseenter` event on any of these `.articles` we inject new html into the hovered over `.articles` from the array `newContArr`, the items of this array could be explicitly entered in javascript or could be retrieved from DOM elements with `display:none` applied on them and we won't change their display value ever.

the way we inject the correct original and also the new content to the exact `.articles` element is by already giving each one an attribute `data-num` dynamically in javascript in the same code part which extracted the original content.

[**JS Fiddle 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/erknavar/)

```js
var origContArr = [],
    
    // this could be retrieved from hidden elements with display:none
    // or hardcoded in the js
 newContArr = [
  'NEW content of the GREEN div',
  'NEW content of the ORANG div',
  'NEW content of the TOMATO div',
  'NEW content of the SKYBLUE div',
  'NEW content of the NAVY div',
  ],
  articles = $('.articles');
  
//extract the inner html, and push the content to origContArr
articles.each(function(index){
 
  var divHTML = $(this).html();
  origContArr.push(divHTML);
      
  // dynamically set a data-num attribute as an identifier
  $(this).attr('data-num', index);
});

articles.on('mouseenter', function(){
  // inject new content
  $(this).html(newContArr[$(this).attr('data-num')]);

}).on('mouseout', function(){
   // replace new content with the original content
  $(this).html(origContArr[$(this).attr('data-num')]);
});
```

```css
.articles{
  width:400px;line-height:30px;padding:5px;margin:3px 0;color:white;text-align:0;
}

.green{background-color:green;}
.orange{background-color:orange;}
.tomato{background-color:tomato;}
.skyblue{background-color:skyblue;}
.navy{background-color:navy;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="articles green">The ORIGINAL content of the GREEN div</div>
<div class="articles orange">The ORIGINAL content of the ORANGE div</div>
<div class="articles tomato">The ORIGINAL content of the TOMATO div</div>
<div class="articles skyblue">The ORIGINAL content of the SKYBLUE div</div>
<div class="articles navy">The ORIGINAL content of the NAVY div</div>
```

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

<sup>(*)</sup>. check the console

Comment: Interesting. I like your solution better.